# java statements inside printf and loop conditions

Tags: java

```
        System.out.printf("\n"
        + "\nEnter a question: " +  question=stdin.nextLine()
        + "\nEnter a guess: " +  Guess=stdin.nextLine());
```

Produces error "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable".

Also,

```
do
        {
            ...
        } while(System.out.printf("\nWould you? "), stdin.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
```

produces  "Syntax error on token ",", . expected"
I want printf to ignore the stuff that doesn't print anything. How to do so?

Comment: can you post the whole functions in which your lines of codes are?

Comment: In the hope that it helps: In Java, 'Guess' is different from 'guess'

Comment: Also if 'Guess' is a variable, it's a very bad name to choose for a variable. Most Java programs use Class names starting with a capital letter, and variable names starting with a lower case letter. It's not a requirement, but a good convention to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.out.printf() does not allow assigning variables. So your attempt on the following code is wrong.

```
System.out.printf("\n"
        + "\nEnter a question: " +  question=stdin.nextLine()
        + "\nEnter a guess: " +  Guess=stdin.nextLine());
```

Try to change the above to multiple lines of code, after declaring all properly.

```
question=stdin.nextLine();
Guess=stdin.nextLine();
System.out.printf("\n"
        + "\nEnter a question: " +  question
        + "\nEnter a guess: " +  Guess);
```

The following do .. while() statement also have the same problem.

```
do
        {
            ...
        } while(System.out.printf("\nWould you? "), stdin.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
```

try the following

```
String answer = "n";
do
{

...
System.out.printf("\nWould you? ");
answer = <-- Get the user input using System.in -->;

} while (!answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
```

you look like having syntax problem and following C++ way. Try to get hands on some java basics books and you are all set to go ..

Happy coding

Comment: `System.out.printf() does not allow assigning variables` Why do you think so? Try this: `System.out.println(i=3)`. Its actually, you cannot use an assignment in a string concat. `System.out.println("this is i: " + (i = 3));` would work too.

Answer (score 0):

Either `question` or `Guess` is not variable. Perhaps `Guess` is a class, not a variable.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment is not automatically what gets assigned:

```
question = stdin.nextLine ();
```

assigns the result of stdin.nextLine () to question, but the result of the assignment is void, not question.

So your only solution is to work in 2 steps: do the assignment, and then, since nextLine has side effects, print the assigned values with println.

Comment: I wasn't trying to print them, they get printed when they're typed in. I was trying to insert statements into printf statements and loop conditions. I want printf to ignore the stuff that doesn't print anything. How to do so?

Comment: @user93200: `S.o.println` prints either Int, Float, Long, Boolean ... and Strings, and calls `.toString ()` for an Object, if you create a call `S.o.p("foo" + object);` But an assignment isn't an object, which means a call to an assignment is illegal and can't be resolved from the compiler. Wrapping your assignment into method won't help, since initializations to local variables would be lost.